# Calling original callback function with its context

Tags: javascript, callback, this

I have this code:

```
function A() {
  this.name = 'John';  
}
A.prototype.getName = function() {
  return this.name;
}

function B() {

}
B.prototype.callApi = function(cb) {
  var context = arguments[0];
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('server data combine with ' + cb());
  }, 1000);
}

var a = new A();
console.log(a.getName());

var b = new B();
b.callApi(a.getName);
```

I want when getName is executed, the `this` variable points to `a` object.

The problem is that when the `cb` is executed, the `this` is not of the `a instance`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to bind the scope of `this` to `a`:

```
b.callApi(a.getName.bind(a));
```

Comment: That's it.  I thought I tried it but I must have fumbled around enough to miss it.  I'll mark this as the answer.  Thanks.